# How do I undo a *reviewer approve" action?

Tags: support

oops.

[image]

[image]
here is the first one.  i thought it was some kinda correction bot at first, but now i don't get it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** undo *the review actions* you have done, but you can undo the *effect* outside of the review.

For suggested edits:

- If the edit has been applied (e.g. [this edit on your own post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31509)), **rollback** it, or
- If the review is still pending (e.g. [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31510) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31511)), **wait** and hope that other reviewers reject it.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I've rejected the two pending ones.

Comment: it says that it's a *"Community"* edit.  what does that mean?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Edits done by anonymous (aka. unregistered) users are delegated to Community user.

Comment: well then maybe it was legit, but the explanation appears goofy: **"no such thing as aattemx or not, cepux, statex can state anyby any nmw"**  appears someone is on the sauce.

Comment: @AndrewT. (off topic) I also wonder what an *unregistered* user is? How can they *edit* without registering ?

Comment: @Fat32 some sites require users to be registered before they can participate, like asking a question or suggest an edit (e.g. Stack Overflow), but the rest allow unregistered users to ask and suggest an edit (e.g. this site). Try it on incognito browser :)